# PHP / MySQL - Query not fetching any data

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying to set up a page that lists prices of items from a table in a database. Here is my code:

```
<?php
$querylist = mysql_query("SELECT item_name,image,price,added_by FROM values");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($querylist))
{
    echo '<div class="post rareitem" style="margin-right: 15px;float: left;">
    <div class="rarename">
    <strong>';

    // Shows Item Name
    echo $row['item_name'];
    echo '</strong>
    </div>';

    // Shows Item Image
    echo '<div class="rareimage" style="background-image: url(/app/tpl/skins/Mango/images/values/rares/';
    echo $row['image'];
    echo ');"></div>';

    // Shows Item Price
    echo '<div class="rarecontrols">
        <div class="coinsbox"></div>
                    <span>
                    <b> <b>Credits: </b> </b> ';
    echo $row['price'];
    echo '</span>';

    // Shows Who Added the Item
    echo '<div class="addedbox"></div><b><b><span><font color="#c93734"><font color="#c93734">Added By: </font> </font>';
    echo $row['added_by'];
    echo '</span></b></b>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>';
}

?>
```

There is another chunk of code (shown below) that I have based this off of, and it works perfectly fine. I can't seem to get this to work though. I believe it has something to do with the SQL, the syntax, or something. No matter what I do, it produces absolutely no results, yet the code below results exactly as planned. I know for a fact it is not a connection issue because the below code can be placed on the same exact page as the above one and it works fine, however the above does not.

```
<?php
$querylist = mysql_query("SELECT id,username,motto,country,look,rank,account_created,role,account_created,online,last_online FROM users WHERE rank='9' ORDER BY ID LIMIT 20");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($querylist))
{
    echo '
    <div class="team">';

    // Showing Avatar
    echo '<div style="float: left; margin-top:-1px;height: 60px; width: 64px; background: url(http://www.habbo.nl/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?figure=';
    echo $row['look'];echo "&amp;action=wav&amp;direction=3&amp;head_direction=3&amp;gesture=sml&amp;size=m) no-repeat 0px -10px";
    echo "\"/>";

    echo "<img alt=\"badge\" src=\"/app/tpl/skins/habbo/images/icons/";
    echo $row['online'];echo ".gif\"></div>";

    // Flags
    echo "<br/><img src=\"/app/tpl/skins/habbo/images/icons/flags/";
    echo $row['country'];echo ".png";
    echo '" style="float:right;" /> <b><uf>';
    echo $row['username'];echo "</u></b>";

    // Bans & Ticket Count
    $Bans = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `bans` WHERE `added_by` = '" . $row['username'] . "'");
    $BanCount = mysql_num_rows($Bans);
    $Tickets = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `moderation_tickets` WHERE `moderator_id` = '" . $row['id'] . "'");
    $TicketCount = mysql_num_rows($Tickets);

    //Role
    echo "<br/><gb>Role: </b><fi> ";
    echo $row['role'];echo "";
    echo "</i>";

    // Echoing bans & Tickets
    echo "<br/><gb>Bans: </b><fi> ";
    ; echo $BanCount;
    echo "</i>";

    echo " &nbsp; <gb>Tickets: </b><if>";
    ; echo $TicketCount;
    echo "</i>";
    echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

Thanks in advanced, any assistance will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is your `$query_list` have an output?

Comment: **STOP** using deprecated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or PDO. Also check for errors after executing sql statements.

Comment: @aldrin27 Isn't the mysql_fetch_array the output?

Comment: @Jens This code is a part of a CMS that I've been hired to work on, and it's all deprecated which is why I have continued to use mysql_*. I've suggested an upgrade, but the owners refuse.

Comment: Development code HAS to include error reporting. This is a trivial error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/keywords.html) is Reserved Words in mysql it should be on backtick

```
SELECT item_name,image,price,added_by FROM `values`
```

And stop using mysql it is deprecated. Instead use mysqli or PDO

Comment: This code is a part of a CMS that I've been hired to work on, and it's all deprecated which is why I have continued to use mysql_*. I've suggested an upgrade, but the owners refuse. Thank you, however, this fixed the problem!

Comment: Of course, the error message would have told you this